# Using read-line to read from .txt, additional symbols being read. Artifacts of notepad?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

the following is part of homework/preperation for exams: I'm trying to write some clisp code to read lines from a textfile. Empty lines should be included. The following is the code I came up with:

```
(defun read-file (filename)
   (do* ((streamin (open filename))               ;open the file
        content
        (line (read-line streamin nil 'eof)      ;read from file in loop
               (read-line streamin nil 'eof)))
        ((equal line 'eof) (close streamin)       ;close the stream if eof is reached
        (reverse content))
    (setq content (cons line content))))         ;add a read line to the returned symbol
```

The expected output from a textfile created in sublime texteditor (or notepad) which looks as follows:

```
this is

a

test
file
```

is this:

```
("this is" "" "a" "" "test" "file")
```

However, I receive the following:

```
("this is^M" "^M" "a^M" "^M" "test^M" "file^M")
```

Where do the '^M' come from? Are they inserted by notepad? Or are they there because of my code? And what are they anyway? My guess it that they indicate a new line.

If they are inserted by sublime, what alternatives do I have to create the expected output? Notepad does the same. The next step in the exercise is to remove empty lines from the output with a filter function and I suppose this works by comparing the lines with equal to an empty line. However, this is not possible when these ^M are inserted since for instance

```
(equal "^M" (read-line test_file_with_empty_lines))
```

returns NIL. While

```
(equal "^M" "^M")
```

returns T obviously...

Comment: "^M" is maybe [carrige return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) which often inserted by text editor on Windows. In Linux we only use line feed.

Comment: @ymonad yes, was my guess too. Any idea how I get rid of them in my output?

Comment: Maybe you can call `string-right-trim` after reading each line: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_whitespace_from_a_string/Top_and_tail#Common_Lisp

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/clisp/impnotes/encoding.html#make-encoding

Comment: I presume you are working on Windows, which version of Clisp do you have? Pasting the input test on SO breaks invisible characters, maybe you could show the result of calling [hexdump](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/hexdump-for-windows.html) on your file? Or if you have Emacs installed, use hexl-mode to show the actual byte content of your file? I cannot reproduce your example.

Comment: @coredump thank you for joining the discussion. Yes, I am using Windows 10. For CLISP I am using an IDE called 'portacle' with SLIME for LISP. Here is the output of hexdump on my testfile:

    `000000  74 68 69 73 20 69 73 0d 0a 0d 0a 61 0d 0a 0d 0a`
    `000010  74 65 73 74 0d 0a 66 69 6c 65`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading a file with DOS line-end conventions with a system which is expecting Unix line-end conventions.

DOS ends lines with a carriage-return/line-feed pair.  the ASCII code of carriage return is #x0d / 13, which is control M, line-feed is #x0a / 10, which is control J.

The CL names for these characters (which I should have used above) are `#\Return` & `#\Newline` respectively.

A file with DOS line-end conventions will therefore contain sequences like (in hex) `0d0a` to mark line-ends.  Something reading it expecting Unix line-end conventions (just a single `0a`) will then read this as a line whose last character is `#\Return`.

The approach to dealing with this is one of three things:

- assuming you're running on a Unixy machine, use editors which use Unixy line-end conventions (Sublime Text does on OSX anyway);
- if you're on a Windows machine then the Lisp should probably default to assuming the platform's native line-end conventions and translate for you;
- if one or both of the above does not work, or the file has been moved between machines, you need to read the implementation's documentation for `open` to find out how to teach it to use an appropriate external format to read DOS-convention files.

---

It seems you are using CLISP.  If so, and if I read its manual properly,  you probably want to use something like `(open ... :external-format ':dos)`.

---

As an additional note, although your code works, it's not very idiomatic CL and it's also unsafe (what happens if there is an error when reading the file?): you might want to look as section 21.2 of the spec. (I'm deliberately not giving you the answer to this as you've been honest & said it's homework, for which thanks!).

Comment: Thanks you, this is the answer/explanation I've been looking for, and as you said, I'm not necessarily looking for a tutorial on how to complete my work. Would be easier but then it does not stick.
And to address the unsafe nature of the code: it only exists to create the expected output on a given file for the homework, it won't be deployed. It might be interesting to expand the code in the future to cover this, but not for now :)

Comment: By 'unsafe' I didn't mean 'insecure' (sorry!), just that it can leak open files.  What I meant was that is this is code you may *submit* as part of your homework you might well lose marks for it as it is (you would if I was marking it, but I'm not!), as there is a CL construct designed specifically to deal with this problem.